# Django - password validation help text translation

Tags: django, validation, translation

I notice that it's possible that some password valildators do not have Russian language `help_text` default translation. Or they do just I do not know how to use it.

In `setting.py`, `LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'`,

```py
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
        # this validator's help_text is not translated: Your password can’t be too similar to your other personal information.
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
        # This validator's help_text is translated: Ваш пароль должен содержать как минимум 8 символов.
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]
```

only `MinimumLengthValidator` displays translated `help_text` in Russian. others still display English. I wonder how to customise it? anyone can help? Thanks!!